# Upload two files in codeIgniter showing error

Tags: php, codeigniter

my View form multipart

```
<h3>Upload Submission File(doc,docx,pdf,cda,rtf,txt)</h3>
<?php echo form_error('fileToUpload'); ?>
<p>                     
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" title="Upload Submission File" 
       accept="application/pdf, .doc, .docx, .txt, application/msword, .rtf, .cda"/>
</p>

<h3>Upload Additional File (gif,jpeg,png,tiff,pdf)</h3>

<?php echo form_error('additionalUpload'); ?>
<p>                     
<input type="file" name="additionalUpload" id="additionalUpload" title="Upload Additional File" 
       accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png, image/x-tiff, application/pdf" />
</p>
```

My Contoller

```
function submit_article() {
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p style="color:red">', '<br/></p>');

    $my_rules = array(
        array(
            'field' => 'fileToUpload',
            'label' => 'Submission File',
            'rules' => 'callback_is_proper_file'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'additionalUpload',
            'label' => 'Additional File',
            'rules' => 'callback_is_image'
        )
    );

    $this->form_validation->set_rules($my_rules);
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        //ERROR
        $data['title'] = ucfirst('submit Article');
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('submit_article', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    } else {
        //SUCCESS

        $data['title'] = ucfirst('article Submitted');
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('forms_view/submit_article_success', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}



function is_image() {
    if ($_FILES['additionalUpload']['tmp_name'] != '') {

        $config1['upload_path'] = './public/uploads/';
        $config1['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|pdf|tiff';
        $config1['max_size'] = '2048';
        $config1['max_width'] = '0';
        $config1['max_height'] = '0';
        $config1['remove_spaces'] = true;
        $config1['overwrite'] = true;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config1);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('additionalUpload')) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('is_image', $this->upload->display_errors('<p style="color:red">', '<br/></p>'));
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            $this->upload->data();
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}

function is_proper_file() {
    if ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] != '') {
        $config['upload_path'] = './public/uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'doc|docx|pdf|cda|rtf|txt';
        $config['max_size'] = '1024*10';
        $config['max_width'] = '0';
        $config['max_height'] = '0';
        $config['remove_spaces'] = true;
        $config['overwrite'] = true;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('fileToUpload')) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('is_proper_file', $this->upload->display_errors('<p style="color:red">', '<br/></p>'));
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            $this->upload->data();
            return TRUE;
        }
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('is_proper_file', '<p style="color:red">Please select a file to upload.<br/></p>');
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

The additionalUpload field is not required field and filetoupload is a required field. 
when i submit the form by filling all the details except additionalUpload my code works well for me, but when i submit the form with additionalUpload along with aal other details it shows me error "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed." for additionalUpload field..

in other words when i submit the form with one file that is filetoupload which is required its works for me.. and when i submit the form with both the files that is filetoUpload and additionalUpload then its shows me error for the additional upload fields "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.",,  and when i simply submit the form with only  addtionalupload file its do the upload in my upload folder but when i submit with all the fields it shows me error "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed." for the additional Upload filed..

THANKS IN ADVANCE PLEASE HELP ANYONE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $this->load->library('upload');
 $this->upload->initialize($config1);
```

I need to call it like above where as I have called it in this way:

```
 $this->load->library('upload',$config);
```